# GitHub inbox empty but still showing "1" and blue dot

Tags: github

I have cleared my GitHub notification inbox, deleted the browser cache and logged out and back in to GitHub. Still it shows me a "1" next to "Inbox" and the blue notification dot.
How can I fix this?
This happens under Linux with Gnome on both the newest Firefox Developer Edition 124.0b7 and Chromium "Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)".

[image]

Comment: Likely a bug on their end. Contact support

Comment: @DanielA.White: Thanks, I filed a bug report at <https://support.github.com/ticket/2665893>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer by GitHub support successfully got rid of the blue dot:

The issue you are experiencing is a known bug that often occurs when you receive notifications from accounts that have been suspended or marked as spammy. Our engineering team is aware of this issue, and they are actively working to address it. While I cannot make any specific promises regarding updates or changes, please rest assured that your report is being investigated.

In the meantime, there is a workaround you can try. You can mark all notifications as read using our Activity API. To do so, please run the following command, replacing $TOKEN with your personal access token. Note that the token needs to have notifications scope checked.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://api.github.com/notifications
```

Please note that this workaround will not remove the repository from the list of repositories you have received notifications for, which appears on the left panel of the notifications page. Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to edit that list.